# Elasticsearch not listening on 9200

Tags: elasticsearch, connection-refused

I've followed a guide to setup graylog on Ubuntu and am having problems getting elasticsearch to behave. I've installed everything, googled umpteen threads on elasticsearch "connection refused". Found a question/answer about "is it listening on port 9200?" and well.

```
martin@SERVER:/var/log/elasticsearch$ sudo systemctl status elasticsearch

elasticsearch.service - LSB: Starts elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/elasticsearch; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2016-12-20 05:47:11 UTC; 20min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 17637 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 17671 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0

Dec 20 05:47:11 HillhouseTech systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts elasticsearch.

Dec 20 05:47:11 HillhouseTech systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts elasticsearch...

Dec 20 05:47:11 HillhouseTech systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts elasticsearch.

martin@SERVER:/var/log/elasticsearch$ netstat -l -n
Active Internet connections (only servers)

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN

tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN

tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN

tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please tell us Version of Elasticsearch and how much free ram available in your server ?

Comment: is 9200 port bound to any other application?

Comment: Mem:        3521804      626212      788956       59120     2106636     2502436

Comment: Version: 1.7.5-1 - that could be it then

Comment: What is the heap size given for Elastic search and what is the RAM size..?

Comment: Now I got something in the error logs: script.disable_dynamic is not a supported setting, replace with fine-grained script settings.

Comment: Total memory is 3½ GB

Comment: After commenting out a setting about script in the configuration file, ES now actually starts and the curl-test produces the expected results. Now to enable port in firewall and I suppose I'll be able to reach the site on the web as well.

Comment: Hello @Martin I'm having the exact issue you did, did you have a working solution ? do you care to share it ?